# How to do something everytime a certain element is in view using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now every time the user reaches the bottom of my page I update the url hash using this code:

```
var new_page_value = 1;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        new_page_value += 1;
        window.location.hash = 'page-' + new_page_value;
    }
});
```

How can I do the same when the user scrolls past any of the divs with the class "page" in the code below? For example if the user scrolls into view the 1st one the hash should be updated to #page-1 but as soon as they scroll into view the 2nd one the hash should be updated to #page-2 and so on. And if they scroll back to the first the hash should once again be updated to #page-1. Basically the hash should update based on whatever div is in view.

```
<div class="page" data-page-num="1"></div>

<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

<div class="page" data-page-num="2"></div>

<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

<div class="page" data-page-num="3"></div>
```

Comment: `<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />` isn't the best way to style the page... **:)**

Comment: @gdoron I just put the break tags so that code could be used as an example to test any possible solutions out. I'm not actually using that.

Comment: If more than 1 of the `div`s are in view then which one do you pick?

Comment: @w3d good question, I guess whichever is the bottom one that is in view should be picked (if you are scrolling down). If you are scrolling back up the top should be picked. The reason for needing this is because I load new content on my page via ajax executed via infinite scroll kind of like Twitter. My code is set up so that if there is a #page-whatever it loads that "whatever" page. So if I can update the url on scroll each time a new page is loaded, I can have bookmarkable urls.

Comment: If you are already loading content as the user scrolls, can you not update the URL at that stage? Or are you loading content that is just below the viewable page? And I guess this won't include the situation when the user scrolls back up...?

Comment: @w3d I am already doing this at the stage where the ajax call is fired. However if the user scrolls back up and finds something interesting and wants to come back to it later then the page is bookmarked as having the hash of the last page that was loaded not necessarily the one he is looking at at the moment. That's because the hash is updated each time the user reaches the page bottom which is also when the ajax is fired. The hash isn't updated each time the user reaches a new "page" div. In which case the hash would constantly update based on which "page" div is in view.

Answer (score 0):

This code may help, but it might be a little intensive on the client side.

```
var new_page_value = 1;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".page").each(function() {
        var position = $(this).position();
        if($(window).scrollTop() == position.top) {
            new_page_value += 1;
            window.location.hash = 'page-' + new_page_value;
        }
    });

    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        new_page_value += 1;
        window.location.hash = 'page-' + new_page_value;
    }
});
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working as expected. I removed the bottom code for now to just test the problem in question. The hash is never updated, if I replace window.location.hash with just alert(new_page_value) it is never alerted either.